# How to set a right-to-left paragraph in a Tumblr post?

Tags: html, css, localization, hebrew, tumblr

Tumbler used to allow **right aligned paragraphs**, which is useful in RTL languages (e.g., Hebrew or Arabic).

In the past, I'd create Right-to-Left paragraphs - by entering either of the following in the Tumblr post HTML code:

- `<div align="right">`
- `<div style="text-align:right">`

However, following the latest Tumblr "enhancements", these tags *stopped* having effects.

### Anyone knows how to make a right-to-left paragraph in a Tumblr post?

Note: I'm aware that there're Tumblr *themes* that convert *globally* to RTL, but I want the justification to be only per paragraph (or post).

### EDIT 1

Tried [unor](https://superuser.com/users/151741/unor) suggestion.
Unfortunately, Tumblr seems to ignore these html5 tags.
Namely, while [this is the html code of the Tumblr post](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeMWFZSGFrbHVuRFk/view?usp=sharing), the [(Hebrew) paragraphs are still left-aligned](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5McUt95YdeZVFTcHZHZy1GRHc/view?usp=sharing)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the following tag (kudos @unor) will create a *right-justified RTL paragraphs* in a Tumblr post:

```
<div style="text-align: right;" dir="rtl">
```

See [example](http://falkland-islands.tumblr.com/post/115466859645).

### Note:

In `editing mode`, these paragraphs will still show *left-justified*, but the `displayed post` will be *right-justified*.

### Another Note:

This may seem obvious, but is worth mentioning, that the above tags should be inserted while editing the post in HTML view.

Answer (score 0):

(I don’t know and can’t test what Tumblr allows/disallows in post markup; but here’s what they *should* support, ideally.)

If you want *real* RTL, you should **not** use CSS (or the [obsoleted](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) `align` attribute).

For specifying an element’s text directionality, HTML5 provides

- the [`dir` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#the-dir-attribute),
- the [`bdi` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-bdi-element) (for "isolating" content), and
- the [`bdo` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-bdo-element).

If I understand your use case correctly, you could (try to) use one of these:

```html
<p dir="rtl">…</p>

<p><bdo dir="rtl">…</bdo></p>
```

Comment: Thanks @unor: see `EDIT 1` in OP for answer.